# How to Use Metadata-extractor to Determine File Type

Tags: java, metadata-extractor

I'm using metadata-extractor to extract the meta data from image files and this is working great.  What I'd like to know is if there is a way that the metadata-extractor library can tell me the type of file I'm processing.  I have some files that are supported file types, but they lack a file extension.  Is there an API that'll just give me the file type, assuming I'm passing in a supported file type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the `FileTypeDetector` class.

I added a page about its use to the project wiki:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/File-Type-Detection

In a nutshell:

```
FileType fileType = FileTypeDetector.detectFileType(myStream);

if (fileType == FileType.Jpeg) {
    // ...
} else if (fileType == FileType.Png) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Actually, `FileTypeDetector`'s constructor is private and `detectFileType()` is a static method.  Other than that, the code works great.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Fixed.

Comment: I noticed that FileType has no enums for MOV, MP4, M4V, 3G2, 3GP and 3GP, yet these are supported types, yes?

Comment: @mbmast video types are currently only supported in the .NET version of the library. The code is there and it shouldn't be hard to port if someone has time to put a PR together.